# Cannot extract cipher text using parse_str

Tags: php, string, parsing, encryption

I have a string

```
$data=    ccnumber=6XgVr1EmHI7MoAJNQTMLoZ5IB7XyQ+PS5UMVxapCJT+hAlr7wm+QrIz768+fQ4zBM1QKB6dFXHvn7oR/dL3qMTwyf9Qgls7CvX/IFc+BVJcTwXKXEpD47XOoFFjJkpyGrGFb2TUMwNDkapd6XZWYM4uhXm3fPBoMLxG6G/Po9r39wBvG6szmao7jxkAZmaYMZ/BZXmC9l8YceavKs3cb7dpvW4858tDmUylZHCAcByqivTVj67VIfS1zudq1bDN6YhimrLKDtZx56lMerm6+NhaBclx0yEZxc66tVJYnE9CzUCYl+b4Q1OZyGCY31fz6DVA6KHWKHEkf7XGPgthhcQ==&cvv=111&name=sam
```

In which each variable is separated by `&`, like:

```
$data=ccnumber={}&cvv={}&name={}
```

and I'm using `parse_str` to parse the strings into variables like this:

```
parse_str($data);
```

All other values are parsed correctly, but I can't parse the ciphertext properly. What can be a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because parse_str function assumes you are parsing a part of URL, so it decodes specific characters. In your case, it should be converting `+` into space. You can try a regular expression:

```
preg_match('@ccnumber=(.*?)&@', $data, $m);
$cipher = $m[1];
```

Comment: What is the parameter $m ?

Comment: It stores matched parts of the string

Comment: you should not be.. I just verified it works. try `var_dump($m)` after preg_match.